# STRDBG command works only for one run

Tags: ibm-midrange

When i put a program in Debug using STRDBG, it seems that I always have to do an ENDDBG and re-start debugging again if I want to debug multiple times. Why is this the case? Shouldn't the program go into Debug mode each time I call it till ENDDBG is issued?

Comment: Good question, I have wondered this myself, STRISDB works as you describe.

Comment: It is ironic that @MordernRPGSoldier is using the old STRDBG debugger rather than the current (can't call it new as it has been around for years) SEP debugger. Makes me think he is using the old green screen SEU editor which hasn't been updated with new features of the RPG language for at least six years (its last update was three OS releases ago).

Comment: Probably hit F12 which isn't cancel its run.  Program is still in debug.

Comment: @jkmurphy Sorry not very modern I know, but this is what my work place standards require me to do

Comment: That's too bad. The current stuff is so much more productive.

Answer (score 2):

If you use F10 to exit the initial DSPMODSRC screen, then it will stop at the program's entry point when you call the program, but it won't actually set a breakpoint.

So either 1) set a breakpoint in the initial screen or 2) 
set a breakpoint when the DSPMODSRC screen shows again after you call your 
program.

I often do it the second way, since it saves time trying to find the entry point for a large program.

Answer (score 0):

to Debug multiple times.  Set a breakpoint so that subsequent executions stop in the program you are debugging.